# HDMI display behavior on startup

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have a display connected to the HDMI port of my laptop. When I start up the computer with the display plugged in, the built-in display does not turn on, and the external display becomes the primary. I can fix the issue by removing and reconnecting the HDMI cable, but I am curious as to why this behavior is the default.

- OS 10.10.4
- MacBook Pro Retina 15" mid 2015 (model 11,5)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the external display set as the primary display.  Take a look at this article on how to set your primary display.

[Set the Primary Display on a Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2010/04/27/set-the-primary-display-mac/)

Comment: I'm curious how having the display set as the primary would cause this problem. I have many users setup with their external monitor set as the primary that do not complain about this problem.

Comment: Try reconfiguring and see what happens.  Also what is the make/model/settings of the external monitor?